# FLAP T has two versions?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics, accent, flapping

everyone, my question is about the flap T. I'm not a native American English speaker, but I hear the difference between flap t in pretty (some natives pronounce it like the Spanish R, some like a soft D) and flap t in ability (this sounds like a soft D). This is at least how I perceive the flap T. So my questions is do you guys hear any difference (please state whether you're a native or not) in flap T in these two links:

https://youtu.be/P-lBlZ3hqKc?t=616

- pretty - sounds like the Spanish R to me

https://youtu.be/zILgK7OKIdg?t=389

- ability - sounds like soft D to me

Comment: There is a range of acceptable pronunciations of the flap T, and I believe these are close to the opposite ends of the range. You're probably hearing them as two different sounds because they sound like two different sounds in your native language. But in American English, they're both flap T's.

Comment: Lots of allophones of /t/ in English.  Could you use IPA to clarify what you are asking, i.e. [ɾ]?

Comment: I don't hear the R sound in clip 1. But some people pronounce "pretty" with a more staccato sound. Ex. Larry David's "pretty, pretty good" catch phrase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjvnP3s6kNY

Comment: Can you say what 'the flap T' means, please?

Is that to do with phonetics, or what?